# Is it possible to swap out a base class in C++?

Tags: c++

Say I have a base class A1 and derived classes B1 and B2. For example (contrived):

```
class A1
{
public:
    int foo(int input);
};

class B1: public A1
{
public:
    int bar(int input) { return foo(input); }
};

class B2: public A1
{
public:
    int bar(int input) { return foo(foo(input)); }
};
```

Is it possible to create classes C1 and C2 that are the same as B1 and B2, but derived from A2 instead of A1, without having to redefine "B"? i.e. I just want to swap out "foo" for another function in C1 and C2, without redefining as follows:

```
class A2
{
public:
    int newFoo(int input);
};

class C1: public A2
{
public:
    int bar(int input) { return newFoo(input); }
};

class C2: public A2
{
public:
    int bar(int input) { return newFoo(newFoo(input)); }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

This<sup>1</sup> is what templates are for:

```
template<class T>
struct Template : T
{
    int bar(int input) { return this->foo(input); }
};

using B1 = Template<A1>;
```

You can use a wrapper class that delegates the member function with the different name:

```
struct A2Wrapper : A2 {
     int foo(int input) { return newfoo(input); }
};


using C1 = Template<A2Wrapper>;
```

<sup>1</sup> I.e. substituting a type in a definition.

Comment: I get an error on the "using" line "error: expected nested-name-specifier before..."

Comment: @tyebillion are you using C++11 or later? If not, use `typedef` instead, eg: `typedef Template<A1> B1; ... typedef Template<A2Wrapper> C1;`

Comment: Yeah, I added "C++11" to my project and the error went away.

Comment: Why use "struct" and not "class"?

Comment: @tyebillion Because all members and bases are public. Struct is convenient, since it defaults to public.